# Javascript conditional within function datecalendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, date

Morning!

I have this question:

This function:

```
 calendar_arrival.datepicker({
    beforeShow: function () {
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('departure').addClass('arrival');
    },
    minDate: mindate,
    dateFormat: format,
    closeText: "Close",
    currentText: "",
    firstDay: 0,
    nextText: " >>",
    prevText: "<< ",
    monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthNamesShort: monthNamesShortArray,
    dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    isRTL: false,
    onClose: function () {
      var minDate = calendar_arrival.datepicker('getDate');
      if (minDate) {
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 2);
      };
      calendar_departure.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate || 1).on('focus', function () {
        $(this).trigger('blur');
      }); // Date + 1 or tomorrow by default

      if (convertDates) {
        populateCalendar(calendar_arrival);
        populateCalendar(calendar_departure);
      }
    }
```

Has 3 parameters that I would like to change depending the language:

monthNames

dayNames

dayNamesShort

dayNamesMin

I'm trying to use a conditional for example:

```
if ($('html').hasClass('smrt-es')) {
  var monthNames = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
} 
else if ($('html').hasClass('smrt-en')) {
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
}
```

But not works... gives and error in the console.

I'm wondering if any of you has a quick solution.

Thanks so much!
Rob

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try declaring the `monthNames` as default outside of the conditional, and then update its value based on the language:

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

if ($('html').hasClass('smrt-es')) {
  monthNames = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
}

calendar_arrival.datepicker({
  // ...
  monthNames: monthNames,
  // ...
});
```

Do the same for the other parameters `dayNames`, `dayNamesShort`, and `dayNamesMin`.

Comment: This is perfect Gabriel! I updated for all parameters and working fine. Thanks so much for your solution, have a great day!